# MIPS: comparing first element of two arrays

Tags: arrays, mips

```
function:


la $s0, array1      # loads address of array1 into $s0
lw $t8, ($s0)       # loads word contained in $s0 into $t8

la $s1, array2      # loads address of array2 into $s1
lw $t9, ($s1)       # loads word contained in $s1 into $t9

beq $t8, $t9, count # if first element of arrays is equal --> count
j end

count: 

la $t7, counter     # loads address of count into $t7
lw $t3, ($t7)       # loads word contained in $t7 into $t3
addi $t3, $t3, 1    # increments count by 1
sw $t3, counter     # now count var contains 1


printcount: 

li $v0, 4               # print string syscall code  
la $a0, prompt3     # prints "number of same elements: "
syscall

la $t6, counter     # loads address of count into $t6
lw $t5, ($t6)       # loads word contained in $t6 into $t5
li $v0, 1               # print integer syscall code
move $a0, $t5       # move integer to be printed into $a0
syscall


end:

    li $v0, 10          # system code halt
syscall
```

Hi, this section of a program is supposed to compare the first element of two arrays (which are user inputted, I've confirmed that the arrays are stored correctly), and if those elements are equal, the 'counter' will be increased by 1, and printed so that I know if it worked correctly.

The problem is that it always prints '1', no matter if the two elements are equal or not equal. What could be causing this?

Comment: You use `count` as a code label and as a data item - it really can't be both.

Comment: thanks, I copied the code incorrectly. Should be the right code now.

Comment: forgot to add condition if two were not equal. Added.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code ends up executing the instructions at label `count` whether or not the branch is taken. Try something like a `bne` instead of a `beq`:

```
bne $t8, $t9, skip_count # if first element of arrays not equal --> skip_count


count: 

la $t7, counter     # loads address of count into $t7
lw $t3, ($t7)       # loads word contained in $t7 into $t3
addi $t3, $t3, 1    # increments count by 1
sw $t3, counter     # now count var contains 1

skip_count:
```

Comment: thanks, I just realized that after I posted the last comment, lol. Code works as desired now.